# SPARQLWrapper : problem in querying an ontology in a local file

Tags: python, url, sparql, owl, sparqlwrapper

I'm working with SPARQLWrapper and I'm following the documentation. Here is my code:

```
queryString = "SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o. }"

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://example.org/sparql")# I replaced this line with 
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("file:///thelocation of my file in my computer")

sparql.setQuery(queryString)

try :
   ret = sparql.query()
   # ret is a stream with the results in XML, see <http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-XMLres/>
except :
   deal_with_the_exception()
```

I'm getting these 2 errors:
1- The system cannot find the path specified
2- NameError: name 'deal_with_the_exception' is not defined

Comment: for a local file you should not use SPARQLWrapper but core `rdflib` SPARQL support, i.e. you load the file and then do https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try it.

Comment: is it possible to use rdflib for an owl ontology ?

Comment: why should it not? As long as you have the file in any serialization that rdflib can read and if you still want to use SPARQL (which is a query language for RDF), sure - yes. Another Python lib working on the OWL level (axioms, class expressions, etc. ) is `owlready2`

Answer (score 1):

You need a SPARQL endpoint to make it work.   Consider setting up *Apache Fuseki* in your local computer.  See https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/jena

Comment: well, or just use the in-memory SPARQL support of `rdflib`: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html - I mean, SPARQLWrapper is nothing more than remote SPARQL endpoint support for `rdflib`